# Regular expression for getting exact number

Tags: regex, numbers

I have some comma separated numbers in a string out of which I want to match a specific number. For the example string "18, 34, 22, 9, 2, 56" I want to match the number "2" but not the two "2s" in 22. How can I obtain that?

Comment: Your input is incomplete. So you only want to catch 2. What about 333? Or 99? Do you only want to catch single digit nunmbers or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this regular expression `\b2\b` replace `2` with your value

Comment: Why haven't I thought of that?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve that without a regular expression using ordinary string functions which are provided by most of the prog languages. For example one solution in Python. Add a comma at the start and the end:

```
s=", 18, 34, 22, 9, 2, 56,"
s.find(', 2,')
```

In case the search string can't be found the function returns -1. In case you insist on a regexp the pattern could look the same.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe not the best method but you can try something like this

```
                string NUmbers= "18,22,34,52";
                string[] NewNos=NUmbers.Split(',');

                for(int i=0;i<NewNos.Length;i++)
                {
                    if(NewNos[i].ToString().Contains("2"))
                    {
                    //do whatever you want

                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use grep

```
echo "18, 34, 22, 9, 2, 56" | grep -E -o "^2,| 2,| 2$"
```

and substitute '2' in grep regex by any number you search in your comma separated numbers string